# how to refresh a flatlist component from a screen when going back to the screen with new data fetched (React Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, uirefreshcontrol

I'm trying to do an app where you can create some projects, to do so on the main screen ("ProjectsScreen") I have a `<ProjectsList/>` component that takes the data from fetchProjects when rendered.

The problem comes after a new project is created. To create a project im navigating to "CreateProjectScreen" where, when the new project is created, I'm nagivating back to "ProjectsScreen" the `<ProjectsList/>` is not updating with the new data.

The new data after creating a project its saved correctly but the `FlatList` is not refreshed, at this moment I've achieved so with a scroll-to-refresh

How can I refresh the `FlatList` when I am back on ProjectScreen

Thats the structure of the code

```
-ProjectsScreen
--ProjectsList
---FetchProjects
-CreateProjectScreen
```

I add the code bellow

`ProjectsScreen`:

```
const ProjectsScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [apiResult, setApiResult] = useState(null);
  const [apiError, setApiError] = useState(null);
  const { reloadProjects } = useProjects();
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  useEffect(() => {
    reloadProjects();
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{t("title.projects")}</Text>
      <View style={styles.viewContainer}>
        <View style={styles.projectsContainer}>
          <ProjectsList navigation={navigation} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <StyledButton
            whiteBtn={true}
            title={t("buttons.new_project")}
            navigation={navigation}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("CreateProject")}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Project list component:

```
const ProjectsList = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { projects, isLoading, reloadProjects } = useProjects();
  const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);

  const onRefresh = useCallback(() => {
    setRefreshing(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      reloadProjects();
      setRefreshing(false);
    }, 2000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {isLoading ? (
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" colors={COLORS.primary} />
      ) : (
        <FlatList
          data={projects}
          keyExtractor={(project) => project.uuid}
          renderItem={({ item: project }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Upload", { project })}
            >
              <View style={styles.projectContainer}>
                <View
                  style={{
                    flexDirection: "row",
                    justifyContent: "space-between",
                  }}
                >
                  <Text style={styles.title}>{project.name}</Text>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => handleDeletePress(project, reloadProjects)}
                  >
                    <Image style={{ marginTop: 12 }} source={icons.del} />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                <Text style={styles.description}>{project.description}</Text>
                {/* <Text>UUID: {project.uuid}</Text> */}
                {project.models && project.models.length > 0 && (
                  <View style={styles.modelsContainer}>
                    {/* <Text style={styles.modelsHeader}>Models:</Text> */}
                    <FlatList
                      data={project.models}
                      keyExtractor={(model) => model.uuid}
                      renderItem={({ item: model }) => (
                        <View style={styles.modelContainer}>
                          {/* <LinearGradient colors={['#FF4D00', '#FF00D6']} style={styles.gradient}> */}
                          <Text style={styles.modelsName}>{model.name}</Text>
                          <Text style={styles.modelsDesc}>
                            {model.description}
                          </Text>
                          {/* <Text>UUID: {model.uuid}</Text> */}
                          {/* </LinearGradient> */}
                        </View>
                      )}
                      showsHorizonralScrollIndicator={false}
                      horizontal
                    />
                  </View>
                )}
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          refreshing={refreshing} // Added pull to refesh state
          onRefresh={onRefresh} // Added pull to refresh control
          ListEmptyComponent={
            <Text style={{ fontSize: SIZES.medium }}>
              {t("error.projects")} :( {"\n\n"}
              {t("error.refresh")}
            </Text>
          }
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

fetchProjects:

```
const useProjects = () => {
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const fetchProjects = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("access_token");
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    };

    try {
      const response = await axios.get("http:/asof/v1/projects/", config);

      if (!response.status === 200) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
      } else {
        setProjects(response.data);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      console.error("Error fetching repositories:", error.message);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProjects();
  }, []);
  return { projects, isLoading, reloadProjects: fetchProjects };
};

export default useProjects;
```

CreateProjectScreen:

```
const initialValues = {
  name: "",
  description: "",
  models_uuid: [],
};
const sendApi = async (
  values,
  setApiResult,
  setApiError,
  { navigation },
  reloadProjects
) => {
  try {
    // Obtén el token de AsyncStorage
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("access_token");

    // Configuración de la solicitud
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    };

    // Datos del cuerpo de la solicitud
    const data = {
      name: values.name,
      description: values.description,
      models_uuid: values.models_uuid,
    };

    // Realiza la solicitud POST
    const response = await axios.post("http://asof/v1/projects/", data, config);

    // Maneja la respuesta
    if (response.status === 201) {
      console.log("Project created successfully");
      Alert.alert("Project created successfully");
      navigation.navigate("ProjectsScreen");
      reloadProjects();
      // Si es necesario, puedes manejar el resultado de la API
      setApiResult(response.data);
    } else {
      console.log(response);
      setApiError("Error al crear el proyecto");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    setApiError(error.message);
    console.log("Error en la solicitud POST:", error);
  }
};
function CreateProjectScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [apiResult, setApiResult] = useState(null);
  const [apiError, setApiError] = useState(null);
  const { login } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { reloadProjects } = useProjects(); // Obtén reloadProjects del hook useProjects
  const [selectedModelUUIDs, setSelectedModelUUIDs] = useState([]);
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  const handleModelsSelect = (modelUUIDs) => {
    setSelectedModelUUIDs(modelUUIDs);
    console.log("Modelos seleccionados: ", selectedModelUUIDs);
  };
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{t("title.create")}</Text>
      <Formik
        validationSchema={ProjectValidationSchema}
        initialValues={initialValues}
        onSubmit={async (values) => {
          values.models_uuid = selectedModelUUIDs;
          console.log(values);
          console.log("Submitting project:", values);
          await sendApi(
            values,
            setApiResult,
            setApiError,
            { navigation },
            reloadProjects
          );
        }}
      >
        {({ values, handleChange, handleSubmit }) => {
          const { name, description, password, repeatPassword } = values;
          return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>{t("name")}</Text>
              <FormikInputValue
                value={name}
                onChangeText={handleChange("name")}
                name="name"
                placeHolder={t("name")}
                image={icons.user}
              />
              <Text style={styles.text}>{t("description")}</Text>
              <FormikInputValue
                value={description}
                onChangeText={handleChange("description")}
                name="description"
                placeHolder={t("description")}
                image={icons.mail}
              />
              <ModelsList onModelsSelect={handleModelsSelect} />
              <View style={styles.loginButton}>
                {apiError && (
                  <Text style={{ color: "#ff0000" }}>
                    {t("error.api_error")}: {apiError}
                  </Text>
                )}
                <StyledButton
                  onPress={handleSubmit}
                  title={t("buttons.create")}
                  whiteBtn={true}
                />
              </View>
            </View>
          );
        }}
      </Formik>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

I'm successfully getting the new data after adding anew project but no clue on how to refresh the component from main screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use useFocusEffect and useCallback to re-refetch data everytime screen is in focus.

```
 useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
        refetchSomeData();
    }, []),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your ProjectsScreen, you call `reloadProjects` inside the `useEffect` hook. You can try to change the `useEffect` with `useFocusEffect` from **react-navigation** library

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/

**Another workaround can be if you pass a property during navigation back to the project screen.**

```
    if (response.status === 201) {
        console.log("Project created successfully");
        Alert.alert("Project created successfully")
        navigation.navigate("ProjectsScreen")
        reloadProjects()
        // Si es necesario, puedes manejar el resultado de la API
        setApiResult(response.data);
    } else {
        console.log(response);
        setApiError("Error al crear el proyecto");
    }
```

Where you call `navigation.navigate("ProjectsScreen")` you can do `navigation.navigate("ProjectsScreen", {lastTimeReloadedAt: new Date().getTime() })`. // if you want to reload the projects everytime you navigate back to this screen.

```
    if (response.status === 201) {
        console.log("Project created successfully");
        Alert.alert("Project created successfully")
        setApiResult(response.data);
        navigation.navigate("ProjectsScreen", { 
            lastTimeReloadedAt: new Date().getTime() 
        })
        // reloadProjects() No need to call this here.
        // Si es necesario, puedes manejar el resultado de la API
    } else {
        console.log(response);
        setApiError("Error al crear el proyecto");
    }
```

Now you can modify your **ProjectsScreen** to

```
const ProjectsScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {
const [apiResult, setApiResult] = useState(null);
const [apiError, setApiError] = useState(null);
const { reloadProjects } = useProjects()
const { t } = useTranslation()

useEffect(() => {
  reloadProjects()
}, [route.params.lastTimeReloadedAt])

...}
```

In this case everytime lastTimeReloadedAt is different your app will reload the projects.